why is bitnami/mongodb slow to start
Why does it take +3 minutes for the server to bootstrap? And how do I make it faster?
The server is not available on port 27017 during the whole period.
Unable to find image 'bitnami/mongodb:4.4.15' locally
4.4.15: Pulling from bitnami/mongodb
Digest: sha256:916202d7af766dd88c2fff63bf711162c9d708ac7a3ffccd2aa812e3f03ae209
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitnami/mongodb:4.4.15
mongodb 12:55:46.34 
mongodb 12:55:46.34 Welcome to the Bitnami mongodb container
mongodb 12:55:46.34 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
mongodb 12:55:46.34 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
mongodb 12:55:46.34 
mongodb 12:55:46.34 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB setup **
mongodb 12:55:46.35 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MONGODB_* env vars...
mongodb 12:55:46.38 INFO  ==> Initializing MongoDB...
mongodb 12:55:46.39 INFO  ==> Deploying MongoDB from scratch...
mongodb 12:55:46.39 DEBUG ==> Starting MongoDB in background...
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 45
child process started successfully, parent exiting
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.2:27017
mongodb 12:55:47.20 INFO  ==> Creating users...
mongodb 12:55:47.20 INFO  ==> Creating root user...
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6675785385b4afdcb7d7dfad
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.0
Using MongoDB:      4.4.15
Using Mongosh:      1.5.0

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/


To help improve our products, anonymous usage data is collected and sent to MongoDB periodically (https://www.mongodb.com/legal/privacy-policy).
You can opt-out by running the disableTelemetry() command.

------
   Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
   metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).
   
   The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
   and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
   improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.
   
   To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
   To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
------

test> db.getSiblingDB('admin').createUser({ user: 'root', pwd: 'password-123', roles: [{role: 'root', db: 'admin'}] })
{ ok: 1 }
test> mongodb 12:59:09.55 INFO  ==> Users created
mongodb 12:59:09.55 INFO  ==> Writing keyfile for replica set authentication...
mongodb 12:59:09.59 INFO  ==> Configuring MongoDB replica set...
mongodb 12:59:09.59 INFO  ==> Stopping MongoDB...
mongodb 12:59:10.61 DEBUG ==> Starting MongoDB in background...
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 154
child process started successfully, parent exiting

